# Drop Column in Pandas Dataframe based on Row Conidtion

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe and I would like to drop any column that has 0-Flat in the "Trade" row. How would I go about doing that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job

```
headers_to_drop=[header for header in df.columns if (df[header]=="0-Flat").any()]
df=df.drop(headers_to_drop,axis=1)
```

The code first loops over all the columns and checks if there is any columns with the string and drops the selected columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` beside `dropna()` to look through the whole df and remove all columns that contained the 0-Flat string

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column1' : ['1', '2', '3', '0-Flat'],
    'Column2' : ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    'Column3' : ['1', '2', '0-Flat', '0']
})

df.replace('0-Flat', np.nan).dropna(axis = 1)
```